# How to perform a general linear model with random intercept with data?

Tags: anova, spss

How to perform a general linear model with random intercept with my data with SPSS or R?

I would like to know if the CO2 emission is significantly different between my treatments. My sampling design looks like that (it is not real data):

[image]

**More details:** I did a factorial experiment with two factors resulting in 6 treatments. For each treatment, I have 10 replicates. To increase my number of replicate, I sampled over time (the 10 pots each time), and this for 3 differents dates. I want to compare the results of each treatment, eg. Flooded 2H at 27°C with Flooded 6H at 27°C, or Flooded 2H at 27°C with Flooded 2H at 28°C. Also, I would like to know if overall the impact the impact of temperature on CO2 is significant or not, same for the level of flooding.

**Thanks a lot for your help!!!!**

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.

Comment: Questions that are only about software (e.g. error messages, code or packages, etc.)
are generally off topic here. If you have a substantive machine learning or
statistical question, please edit to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Fit a general linear model with random intercept. CO2 emission is response variable. Temperature and flooding, and their interaction are covariates. The date specific random intercept is needed to count the similarity of CO2 from the single day.